# Save my Objects through serialization or make an XML file

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization

I want a build an application, it's my first time so I have come up with a dilemma. In my application I have `Persons` and `Projects` and its one has its attributes. A project is done by some persons, and in each Project there is a Coordinator.

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mailAddress;
    private String ID;

   //more
}
```

also I have a Coordinator person:

```
public class Coordinator extends Person
{
       private String type;
       //more code
}
```

and then I have projects

```
public class Project
{
    private String projectInfo;
    private String nameOfProject;
    private int projectID;
    //more code
}
```

My dilemma is this. Should I store all the objects to a list or HasMap and then through object serialization to my disk or should I make an XML representation (like below) and then read my XML with a DOM parser? In XML way, everytime I will run the application, I will have to create my objects again, right? On the contrary with the serialization I will just read again my Objects from the disk.

```
<project>
    <active></active>
    <complete></complete>
    <name></name>
    <info></info>
    <coordinator></coordinator>
    <level1> //each project is distributed to different levels.
        <cordinator> </cordinator>
        <budget></budget>
        <startDate></startDate>
        <endDate></endDate>
        <totalTasks> </totalTasks>
        <complete></complete>
        <task1>
            <cordinator> </cordinator>
            <personInvolved></personInvolved>
            <personInvolved></personInvolved>
            <personInvolved></personInvolved>
            <personInvolved></personInvolved>
            <budget></budget>
            <startDate></startDate>
            <endDate></endDate>
            <complete></complete>
        </task1>
        <task2>
            //same as task1
        </task2>
    </level1>
    <level2>
            //same as level1
    </level2>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice between serializing using Java or XML doesn't depend on where you'd like to serialize it to.  Both can be saved to a file.  Java serialization dependent on the fact that every process reading the file is a Java program.  (Nothing besides a Java program could read that format.)  XML however is about interoperability.  Any type of program can read an XML file and load in that data through some sort of library (JAXB or other non-Java XML serialization libraries).

Maintaining compatibility of serialized Java objects can be troublesome as the class changes, but it's not insurmountable.  I don't try it though.  If that were a factor for you, you might want to consider XML even if only Java programs were going to read it.

So the issue is -- who needs to read the data you're writing, and what are your needs for writing it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is the serialization, you can write down the object you want and easily read it:

- [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) an useful example
- [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) the official docs form Oracle

Serialize Person p:

```
try {
     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/your_filename.ser");
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
     out.writeObject(p);
     out.close();
     fileOut.close();
}
catch(IOException i) {
     // error management
}
```

Deserialize Person p:

```
try {
     FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/tmp/your_filename.ser");
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
     p = (Person) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     fileIn.close();
}
catch(IOException i) {
     // error management
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
     // error management
  }
```

Comment: Please write the actual code here to prevent link rot.